# Align form elements with css

Tags: css, forms

I am working on a form on my webpage: http://www.xn--l-klubben-k8a.dk/opret-egen-oel/

I would like the the box with the text that says "Kommentar til duften" to align with the two boxes on the right, but beneath them.

I tried the following css, which helped me to get the two boxes to float right and vertically align to the top:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1050px) {

div#fscf_div_field3_9, div#fscf_div_field3_10, div#fscf_div_field3_11 {
  float:right !important;
  clear:none !important;
  width:45% !important;
  display:inline-block;
  }

#FSContact3 {
  max-width: 590px !important;
  }

#FSContact3 div {
  vertical-align:top;
  }

#fscf_div_field3_4, #fscf_div_field3_5, #fscf_div_field3_6, #fscf_div_field3_7, #fscf_div_field3_8 {
  width:50% !important;
  clear:none !important;
  display:inline !important;
  }

#fscf_div_clear3_4, #fscf_div_clear3_5, #fscf_div_clear3_6, #fscf_div_clear3_7, #fscf_div_clear3_8, #fscf_div_clear3_9, #fscf_div_clear3_10, #fscf_div_clear3_11 {
  clear:none !important;
  display:inline !important;
  }

#fscf_submit_div3 {
  width:50% !important;
  }
}
```

I feel like I just need to change one simple thing, but I cannot work out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have:

```
#fscf_form3 div {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

If you increase it let's say to 11 you can see that the box goes to the right and properly aligns. Basically using the proper selectors you need to increase either the `margin-top` of the `div` or the `margin-bottom` of the `div` above it.

Comment: Now i tried this:

    div#fscf_div_field3_11 {
       margin-top:50px !important;
      }

But it only moved the div down, and it did not align with the other boxes on the right.

Comment: Try placing the `margin-bottom` to `#fscf_div_field3_7`.